How to sum 2 values from different queries?
I am trying determine how far below/above a persons average a venue performs. For example the query would return the venue, date, and how far below the expected average it performed. From the data below you can see Pauls average was 100 not including Lakeview so he went exactly his average and Mel went 20 below her average at Lakeview so Lakeview performed -10 on average below peoples average distance.
The query return would look like this:
Venue      Date           Performance
-------------------------------------
Lakeview   12/08/2024     -10

Firstly I need to group by name to get their average. However I only wish to do include their last 5 distances.
I can do that with this query
SELECT name, AVG(distance) as avg_distance
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         database.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) AS seqnum
     FROM database) s
WHERE seqnum <= 5
GROUP BY name

Then I need to group by venue and find the average distance of everyone that performed on this date and at this venue. Which I can do with this query
SELECT venue, AVG(distance)
FROM "database"
GROUP BY venue, date

Then I need to subtract the distance on this date vs their average to see how it performed. What is the easiest way to do this?
Sample Data
Name  Venue     Distance   Date
-------------------------------------
Paul  Holland   120        20/07/2024
Paul  Venus     80         21/07/2024
Paul  Lakeview  100        12/08/2024
Tom   Lakeview  120        12/08/2024
Mel   Lakeview  140        12/08/2024
Mel   Hightail  160        05/05/2024


Please update the post with table DDL and provide executable SQL to populate the table with example data (make it as easy as practical for others to setup the problem). Provide the full expected query result, not just a single point. The example data needs to include enough values to exercise all of the requirements. In this case, there are insufficient data points to demonstrate filtering by only the five most recent per name. Is the combination of name and date unique? If not, then what additional criteria is to be used to determine which are included?

database is a very confusing table name.

Are the average distances for each person calculated across all venues or by excluded venue? The presented query for calculating the average distances does the former, but the description implies that the latter is intended.

One option is to crate a cte (or subquery) with added columns with average distances per name and per venue/date. It could be done using Avg() Over() analytic function.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    tbl ( a_name, venue, distance, a_date ) AS 
      ( Select 'Paul', 'Holland',   120, To_Date('20/07/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') Union All 
        Select 'Paul', 'Venus',      80, To_Date('21/07/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') Union All 
        Select 'Paul', 'Lakeview',  100, To_Date('12/08/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') Union All 
        Select 'Tom', 'Lakeview',   120, To_Date('12/08/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') Union All 
        Select 'Mel', 'Lakeview',   140, To_Date('12/08/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') Union All 
        Select 'Mel', 'Hightail',   160, To_Date('05/05/2024', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
      ), 

... cte grid to get averages per name (last 5 dates) and per venue/date (all distances)
    grid AS 
      ( SELECT  a.*, 
                Round(Avg(Case When rn_name <= 5 Then a.distance End) Over(Partition By a_name ), 2) as avg_name, 
                Round(Avg(a.distance) Over(Partition By venue, a_date ), 2) as avg_venue_date
        FROM  ( Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By a_name Order By a_name, a_date Desc) as rn_name, 
                       a_name, venue, distance, a_date
                From tbl
              )  a
      ) 

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select    venue, a_date, Sum(avg_venue_date - avg_name) as performance
From      grid 
Group By  a_date, venue
Order By  a_date, venue

/*      R e s u l t : 
venue        a_date      performance
-----------  ----------  -----------
Hightail    2024-05-05         10.00
Holland     2024-07-20         20.00
Venus       2024-07-21        -20.00
Lakeview    2024-08-12        -10.00      */

See the fiddle here.
Addition:
If your table name is database (which is bad but anyway) and if column names /types in that table are name /varchar, venue /varchar, distance /integer and date /date (date is also very, very bad name of a column 'cause it is datatype too) then try to use the complete code like below. There is another (first) cte that should adjust your table to the rest of the code:
WITH    
    tbl AS 
      ( Select t.name as a_name, t.venue, t.distance, t.date as a_date
        From database t
      ), 
    grid AS 
      ( SELECT  a.*, 
                Round(Avg(Case When rn_name <= 5 Then a.distance End) Over(Partition By a_name ), 2) as avg_name, 
                Round(Avg(a.distance) Over(Partition By venue, a_date ), 2) as avg_venue_date
        FROM  ( Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By a_name Order By a_name, a_date Desc) as rn_name, 
                       a_name, venue, distance, a_date
                From tbl
              )  a
      ) 
Select    venue, a_date, Sum(avg_venue_date - avg_name) as performance
From      grid 
Group By  a_date, venue
Order By  a_date, venue


Thanks for your response! Is the first input just done to give you the sample data? How would I do it if I already have all the data in there? I have over 100,000 rows of data so I don't think I will be able to manually put them all in the query.

@undecided000 It is just the sample data that you posted at the end of your question. It is NOT  part of the ansswer. You need just: WITH grid AS ( grid sql code )  Main SQL code

Thank you. It is telling me all the a_ values do not exist? For example a_name.

@undecided000 You need to adjust the code to your context. Put your table name and your column names to make it work. This answer uses the names from saample data not from your database ...

Ah I see. I believe I have made the required adjustments but I get this error.
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <= integer
LINE 4: ...             Round(Avg(Case When database.name <= 5 Then ...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

@undecided000 that is rn_name <= 5 . rn_name is alias from subquery in grid cte. You should adjust just your table name ( instead of mine tbl ), and column names where different.  Column names to be changed with yours are a_name, a_date, venue and distance. Do not change my aliases (e.g. rn_name, avg_name, avg_venue_date). And please do not use database as the table name.

@undecided000 Just posted an addition that might help you ...

Awesome! Thanks mate. It works and thanks for the advice about my names, I'm very new to sql. One thing I changed was in the 4th last line, instead of Sum I wanted Avg. So i just changed that and now it is exactly as i wanted. Thank you so much for your time and wisdom.
